# How to perform Filter on Custom Listview on LazyAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-lazyadapter

Here is My LazyAdapter

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
private Context mCtx; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d,Context context) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mCtx = context;
}


public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name); // name
    TextView desc = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.desciption); // collection
    TextView cost = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.cost); // cost
    TextView category = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtcategory); // cost
    TextView spec = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtspec); // cost
    TextView largeimg = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtlargeimage); // cost


    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.ivcatalouge); // thumb image



    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    name.setText(song.get(FrmShowCatlogue.KEY_MODEL));
    desc.setText(song.get(FrmShowCatlogue.KEY_COLLECTION));
    cost.setText(song.get( FrmShowCatlogue.KEY_MRP));
    category.setText(song.get( FrmShowCatlogue.KEY_CATEGORY));
    spec.setText(song.get( FrmShowCatlogue.KEY_SPEC));
    largeimg.setText(song.get( FrmShowCatlogue.KEY_LARGE));

    largeimg.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            try 
    {
        String filename=song.get(FrmShowCatlogue.KEY_IMAGES.toString());
        filename="thumbs/" + filename;
        // get input stream
        InputStream ims = mCtx.getAssets().open(filename);
        // load image as Drawable
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        // set image to ImageView
        thumb_image.setImageDrawable(d);
    }
    catch(IOException ex) 
    {

        //thumb_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return vi;
}
```

}

I want to perform filter on custom listview which has lazyadapter.
I have already done

```
   inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                //FrmShowCatlogue.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);  

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });
```

**Please help to perform filter on my lazyadapter**.
Lazyadapter is getting data from xml parsing.

Comment: Why don't you google before posting question? There bunch of examples of Filtering listview.

Comment: I am new in Android Development. And not found any good example to understand on custom listview with lazy adapter.

Comment: Please consider this one:  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

The name adapter is not important, since all custom adapters are inherited from some other adapters that have filter features. :)